# Fixed navbar falls behind content

Tags: html, css, navbar, fixed

I have a fixed navbar here.

The problem is that when you scroll down, if you then hover over an element that is essentially behind the navbar, it becomes ontop of the nav bar?

Very strange?

Any advice?

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff; }

    .container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px; }

    nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left; }
    nav .links {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px; }
    nav .links a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: .15s; }
    nav .links a:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: .15s; }
    nav .name {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px; }
    nav .name a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none; }
    nav .name a h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0; }

    .work {
    font-size: 0;
    padding-top: 40px;
    overflow: hidden; }
    .work img {
    max-width: 20%;
    transition: .15s; }
    .work img:hover {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: .15s; }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2c53e1eg/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `z-index: 9;` to `nav`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 9;
}
nav .links {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
nav .links a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: .15s;
}
nav .links a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: .15s;
}
nav .name {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
nav .name a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav .name a h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}
.work {
  font-size: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.work img {
  max-width: 20%;
  transition: .15s;
}
.work img:hover {
  opacity: .8;
  transition: .15s;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="links">

      <a href="#">WORK</a>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#">DRIBBBLE</a>
      <a href="#">BEHANCE</a>
      <a href="#">BLOG</a>
      <a href="#">CONTACT</a>

    </div>

    <div class="name">

      <a href="#"><h2>Tom Walsh</h2></a>

    </div>

  </div>

</nav>

<div class="work">

  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: @TomWalsh Most welcome, As you are new here, Please take a short look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this style

```
.links{z-index:1}
```

Comment: Good approach, but It will be great if we set it to `nav`. Maybe he add some other elements with `position: relative;` and problem will remain same :)